# success message issue in JQuery from Laravel controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have submitted the json response from laravel controller but when it gives error the JQuery section is working fine but when the request succeeds the JQuery gives error that parase error and I am not able to read the data content but it shows the data in log console correctly.

JQuery Ajax code:

```js
event.preventDefault();
url = $('a#sendpropertiesdata').attr('href');
data = new FormData($('#propertiescreateform')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
        // alert(data.msg);
        response = data
        alert(response['code']);
        if (data.code == 0) {
            $('span#error_message').text(data.error).css('color', 'red');
        } else if (data.code == 1) {
            $('span#error_message').text(data.msg).css('color', 'green');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('form#propertiescreateform').remove();
            }, 3000);
        }

    },
    complete: function (data, status) {
        alert(data.code + "     " + status);
        if (data.code == 1) {
            $('span#error_message').text(data.msg).css('color', 'green');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('form#propertiescreateform').remove();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

Controller Code:

```php
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules); 
if ($validator->passes())
{
    $property = new Properties();
    $property->country = $request->country ; 
    $property->city = $request-> housecity ; 
    $property->location = $request->houseaddress ;
    $property->description = $request->propertiesdescription ;
    $property->price = $request->price;
    $property->save();   
          
    return response()->json(['code' => 1, 'msg' => 'data saved successfully']);
}
else
{
    return response()->json(['code' => 0, 'error' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
}
```

Comment: After this line : return response() -> json(['code' => 1, 'msg' => 'data saved successfully']);

there is a closing } which shouldn't be there (the } else { relates to the $validator->passes if clause.

Answer (score 0):

update this line in controller

```
return response() -> json(['code' => 1, 'msg' => 'data saved successfully'],200);
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    .........
    ,
    success: function(data) {

       ........

    },
    error: function(response) {

        ...........
    }
});
```

controller

```
           if ($validator->passes()){
                dd('1');
                $property = new Properties();
                $property->country = $request->country ; 
                $property->city = $request->housecity ; 
                $property->location = $request->houseaddress ;
                $property->description = $request->propertiesdescription ;
 
                $property->price = $request->price; 
                dd('2');
                     $property->save();   
                     dd('3');
                     return response()->json(['code' => 1, 'msg' => 'data saved successfully'],200);
                    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way, still the same.

Comment: i've updated the answer add 'error' section in your ajax and print response

Comment: it does work when the validation is not passed and I get the error but in the success scenario why it doesn't work.

Comment: it only gives object object that is it. when I do JSON.parse() still the same and I used stringify as well but no result still the same.

Comment: update your controller . code in answer.

Comment: I did this but still it's not working the same issue.

Comment: which dd is coming up in your network request ?

Comment: done

"3"               is the message that shows in the log message.

Comment: remove all dd and log response. what is it showing?

Comment: on the log console the response is shown, code 1 and the successful message but it doesn't show in the alert message of my code. showing object object.

Comment: you can't alert an object. make that value to a string to alert

Comment: I did so but it's not working via json parse and stringify but it's still the same, but when it fail still that could works.